# ¿Cómo abrir una imagen en una pestaña diferente?

Tags: php, html

Necesito abrir una imagen en una pestaña diferente ya que la cargo en un modal pero se ve muy pequeña y pues necesito que se vea mas grande este es el código

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
  <a href='img' ><p><img src="img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"> </p></a>
 </div>
```

Pero me manda a otro lado no sé a donde enviarlo o que hacer.

Comment: Agregar `target="_blank"` , además de especificar en `href`del link _(a)_ el mismo valor del `source` _(src)_  de la imagen , `<a href="img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>" target="_blank"><p><...`

Comment: podrias ponerlo en respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería especificar el anchor `target="_blank"` para que se abra una nueva ventana con la `url` especificada en `href` de su enlace *(a)* , que tendrá el mismo valor del `source` de su imagen.

```
<a href='img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>' target="_blank">
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>" 
    style="width: 100%;height: 100%"> </p>
</a>
```

Comment: bien gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

Prueba en en anchor (target="_blank"

```html
    <div class="modal-body">
            <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
       <a href='img' target="_blank"><p><img src="img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"> </p></a>
         </div>
```

Comment: no me sigue mandando a otro lado sin la imagen

Comment: gracias por el intento

Comment: Comprueba la url de la imagen. No es problema del anchor

Comment: no ya gracias ya marque como respuesta la de arriba